# Sharing view presentation mode?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am building an ASP .NET MVC 3 application, and I want to make sure that I am following the MVC guidelines as well as possible.

I have a front page that displays a list of computer games. Now, it has the same way of displaying the items as another page. How would I do this through an MVC perspective?

Would I have a function in my controller that returns a string containing the HTML of the list of games, and then print that out on both pages? Or how would I do this in a proper way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

partial views.  you should be able to find a lot of information about them via search.